# Handle outputstream with openapi generated Resource in spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, outputstream, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I would like to write an OutputStream out of a resource method in Spring, that has been generated by OpenApi Maven plugin.

pom.xml:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0</version>
                   ...
                   <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
```

openapi.yaml:

```
     /api/reason/my-reason-categorization:
    get:
      tags:
        - reason-resource
      operationId: myReasonCategorization
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
```

Resource method implementing the generated interface:

```
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> myReasonCategorization() {
        // how can I connect the servlet outputstream to my business method ?
        createExcel(outputstream);
    }
```

My question is:

Either how can I access the outputstream of the servlet inside the generated method? `ResponseEntity<Resource>` only accepts InputStream stuff, like for example `InputStreamResource`.

Or is it possible to make openapi generate a resource method that offers the outputstream?

I don't want to work with byte arrays, because the generated file might be quite big and memory consuming. I want to write the generated excel file directly to the outputstream.

Comment: Even if you're using InputStreamResource at some point or another it will be transformed into ByteArray from the documentation:
Should only be used if no other specific Resource implementation is applicable. In particular, prefer ByteArrayResource or any of the file-based Resource implementations where possible.
In contrast to other Resource implementations, this is a descriptor for an already opened resource - therefore returning true from isOpen(). Do not use an InputStreamResource if you need to keep the resource descriptor somewhere, or if you need to read from a stream multiple times.

Comment: so use it if you can guarantee that the resources will be 100% open if not use file-based resource or ByteArrayResource

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Karim. I want to use OutputStream. How can I achieve that? Is there something I can add to the openapi specification?

Comment: There is no OutputStream implementation for Resource, Either use FileResource or ByteArrayResource

Comment: ... or don't generate with open-api, right?

Comment: Yeah exactly @andy